# Rivet kinda thing with hole

Tags: rivets

I just received the fractal meshify C (computer case), for this build I wanted to adjust a few things thus I need to disassemble the case.

So in order to prepare myself I got myself 3.2mm rivets and a rivet gun, however upon inspection there is also this 'see through rivet/ring' (see picture on the left). I was wondering how are these called, because I was not aware of them and how do i remove them and replace them :D

[image]

If anyone can help me here much appreciated.

Comment: please add a side view

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Home Improvement.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer of the case to ask?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a grommet or an eyelet to me. Without more information about how the case was constructed it's hard to say if it is important that it be reinstalled the same way or if you could just replace it with a pop-rivet. There are a variety of different types of rivets available, I'm assuming you are talking about pop-rivets because you mention a rivet gun.

I would drill it out with a drill bit just larger than the center hole to remove it. I think you'll find that it is made up of an inner piece and outer piece which are rolled or crimped together at the center to hold in place. If you drill out the very center you will break the crimp/roll and the front and back halves will fall off.